# How do I check the "createPersistentCookie" in ASP.NET Forms Authentication?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

When someone logs into my application and they checked the "Remember Me" checkbox, I set the `createPersistentCookie = true` so that when they come back they don't need to log in again.  However, occassionally, I need to use the `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(NewUserName, [true/false])` so how do I know if they originally set the `createPersistentCookie` to true or not so I can keep it the same as it was when they logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe when you decrypt the cookie you should be left with a `FormsAuthenticationTicket` which you can then query the `IsPersistent` property.

To decrypt:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);
```

References:
[FormsAuthentication.Decrypt() on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.decrypt.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should also remember to set  in your application's web.config to constant value. ASP.NET has tendency to auto generate this values after some time.

For more info please take look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(v=VS.90).aspx