# Change Username ASP.net MVC 3 Membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I am running a ASP.net MVC 3 web application, and using the Membership Provider. I would like to know if its possible to allow the user (or administrator) to change an existing accounts username? I have not found a way to do this. The username is not an email address, but is validated on its uniqueness prior to my attempt at assigning the new name.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The membership provider does not provide a method to update the username.  You will either need to extend the membership providers UpdateUser method or directly interact with the membership tables to allow this change.  However you approach this, keep in mind a few items

1. On update, you will need to check uniqueness of the username much like what happens when a user is created.
2. If the user is logged in and changes their username, you will either need to force them logout and log back in or reissue the AuthenticationTicket cookie.  The reason being, if they change their username, then the authTicket cookie stored username and the actual username not longer match.  If you use `HttpContext.Identity.User.Name` to query your datastore or check authorization to content, you will no longer return any results as that username no longer exists.

Comment: How does one reissue the AuthenticationTicket cookie? At a guess, I'd suggest invoking FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(), but perhaps you know?

Comment: Yup - you've got it.  Basically that will create a new auth cookie and send it back with the response, overwriting the previous auth cookie.  The only thing I can think that may cause someone somewhere issues is that the expiration time on the cookie will be reset.

Comment: I invoked that with the new username (and createPersistentCookie set to false) but I found that neither the old username nor the new one could then be used to log in. Any ideas?

Comment: Logging in with the new/old username is not related to the auth cookie...?  Are you talking about from a login form?

Comment: yep, from a logon form. I assumed that once the Authentication Ticket is reissued that a logon with the new username would be successful.

Comment: Well...its two different issues.  You don't need to log back in when you reissue the auth ticket.  You have already authenticated the user, you are just resetting the username part of the authentication ticket.  As for not being able to actually login with the new username, you would need to check your user store (db) and ensure that it updated the username, did not change the pwd, did not 'deactivate' the user, etc.

Comment: Took a look at my user store as you suggested and found the problem. My issue was that when updating the user, I was inadvertently updating the password with an unhashed version of it, thus validation was failing when logging in. Woops! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I need to do the same thing, but not sure how to set createPesistentCookie in FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(). I can always set it to false, but shouldn't I set it based on whether the user checked "Remember me?" when they logged in? But if so, where to access this value after login?

Comment: Found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113972/how-do-i-check-the-createpersistentcookie-in-asp-net-forms-authentication